# Invalid Configuration Webpack v3.10.0

Tags: node.js, webpack

When i try to run the following command;

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config ./project1/webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod
```

I am getting the following error?

> node : Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised
>   using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config ./project1 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid configu...the API schema.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> - configuration[0].entry should be one of these:    object { : non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string |
>     [non-empty string] | function    -> The entry point(s) of the
>     compilation.    Details:
>
>   - configuration[0].entry['vendor'] should be a string.
>       -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration[0].entry['vendor'][5] should be a string.
>       -> A non-empty string
>   - configuration[0].entry should be a string.
>       -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration[0].entry should be an array:
>       [non-empty string]
>   - configuration[0].entry should be an instance of function
>       -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
> - configuration[1].entry should be one of these:    object { : non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string |
>     [non-empty string] | function    -> The entry point(s) of the
>     compilation.    Details:
>
>   - configuration[1].entry['vendor'] should be a string.
>       -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration[1].entry['vendor'][15] should be a string.
>       -> A non-empty string
>   - configuration[1].entry should be a string.
>       -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration[1].entry should be an array:
>       [non-empty string]
>   - configuration[1].entry should be an instance of function
>       -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.

My webpack.config.vendor.js is;

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill', ,
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'ngx-bootstrap',
    'angular2-useful-swiper',
    'jquery'
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

and for completness my package.json is;

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.10.0-beta.3",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.5",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "5.0.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.9",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.9.1",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.9",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.2",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "style-loader": "0.20.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.7.1",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on

Comment: Couldn't test it, so just a guess: The error indicates for a wrong usage of `entry` in your `serverBundleConfig` and `clientBundleConfig`. `vendor` must not be an array! `entry` itself can be an array. No guarantee, but you could try `entry: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules,` and `entry: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']),`

Comment: @UweMannl thanks for the reply. do you mean adding this to the webpack.config.vendor.js or a referenced file?

Comment: If so where are these files please? as I dont have a serverBundleConfig, nor a clientBundleConfig that I can see in the solution.

Comment: Can't promise it is working, but what I mean: You have a _webpack.config.vendor.js_ (your first file above). There are two variables/consts: `serverBundleConfig` and `clientBundleConfig` (in the `module.exports` part). And in both of the configs, there is an `entry` entry. In this `entry`, replace vendor with the code in my first comment. If it's still unclear, look here: https://pastebin.com/H7yZHkHD ... PS: where is this code from?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I was looking blind and didnt see what you are referring to. Ok I tried removing per your paste bin and i get the error node : Configuration file found but no entry configured.

Comment: So I changed it to be like follows; https://pastebin.com/FhPUb8fi However this then errors with an Unexpected Token error. By the way the code is from the visual studio SPA template, I have changed though to use a few additional plugins. As another test i have create a new project and worked through to find the issue, publishing the blank app works fine, however after I added in my additional packages, and change the nonTreeShakeableModules the publish error reappeared in the new project

Comment: sorry to bombard with comments, but i also tried adding a toString(), i.e. `entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']).toString() }`. This then give the error; `configuration[0].entry should be one of these:
   object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string] | function`

Comment: No problem. Just made some tests and I can't understand, why webpack is complaining. Your code `vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']).toString()` matches what webpack expects in your error message: `{ <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] }`. Some questions: Do you still use webpack 3.10, like said in your package.json? Did you change your `vendor` part in `client-` **and** `serverBundleConfig`? Perhaps you only changed one, and webpack complains about the other side. Could you provide the complete project, so I can look for myself?

Comment: @UweMannl I cant thank you enough for your help. I've been tearing my hair out for days on this. Turns out its a damn typo in the nonTreeShakableModules (not the extra , after the polyfill entry). Only myself to blame, I'm embarassed :S

Comment: No need, can happen all of us ;) A good IDE can help a lot if handeling with JavaScript. At work we use Webstorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). Cost a lot of money, but perhaps you can give the trial a try.